# How to use lean() with mongoose and bluebird?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bluebird

I'm kind of new with Promises and Bluebird. 
I was trying to make a query using Mongoose and Bluebird. 
I've already promisified mongoose and added the **Async** suffix to the find function as you can see in the code below

```
function getLocations() {
  var query = {}
  var selection = {
    coordinates: 1,
    geoFence: 1
  }
  return MyLocation.findAsync(query, selection).lean()
}
```

I've tested it and it works without the `lean()` function, but when I use the `lean()` function the code breaks with the following message

**TypeError: MyLocation.findAsync(...).lean is not a function**
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `MyLocation.find(query, selection).lean().execAsync()`

Comment: Mongoose supports promises [out of the box](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html), too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just marking that the official answer is the one provided by JohnnyHK

```
  MyLocation.find(query, selection).lean().execAsync()
```

Comment: Is there a way to call lean on a mongoose object that was created and not being queried?